# How to write junit for Logging in Java using mockito

Tags: java, logging, junit, mockito

I have to write JUNIT for logging.I am using logback to log messages.
I have string as log type identifier and based on log type i am logging accordingly. I am new to Junit and didnt get much on writting mockito for Logging.
code:

```
switch (logtype) {
   case "ERROR":
      for(String messages:errorMessages)
      {
          LOG.error(messages.replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\t", " "));
      }
      break;
   case "DEBUG": 
      for(String messages:errorMessages)
      {
          LOG.debug(messages.replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\t", " "));
      }
      break;
   case "DEBUG":
      for(String messages:errorMessages)
      {
          LOG.warn(messages.replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\t", " "));
      }
      break;              
   default:
      for(String messages:errorMessages)
      {
          LOG.info(messages.replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\t", " ")); 
      }
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Mockito, I suggest installing a logger and asserting on the log messages that were logged. That way, if you have the logger to formatting, you can assert that the formatting looks correct.

I personally don't recommend adding tests for any logging for info or debug. Adding assertions for fine-grain logging makes it more difficult to add new logging calls to your code.